# Python if statement not working?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I started learning python just now, through the book "Think like a computer scientist" and I have got stuck in some language syntax.

```
def amt():
    amount = input("Enter your amount: ")
    amount = int(amount)
    if amount >= 20:
        twe = amount / 20
        amount = amount - twe * 20
            print("You need to pay %d twenty dollar bills" %(twe))
    if amount >= 10:
        ten = amount / 10
        amount = amount - ten * 10
        print("You need to pay %d ten dollar bills" %(ten))
    if amount >= 5:
        five = amount / 5
        amount = amount - five * 5
        print("You need to pay %d five dollar bills" %(five))
    if amount >= 1:
        one = amount / 1
        amount = amount - one * 1
        print("You need to pay %d one dollar bills" %(one))

amt()
```

when I run this with some input say 7 I get an error message like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dollars.py", line 21, in <module>
    amt()
  File "dollars.py", line 7, in amt
    print("You need to pay %d twenty dollar bills" %(twe))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'twe' referenced before assignment
```

Why isn't the if statement working properly? Even though input value is less than 20 its still entering into the first if statement

Comment: Given `7` as input this code works fine.

Comment: This looks correct. Are you absolutely sure this is the code that is running? Did you save the file before running?

Comment: Since the code looks good I think you are looking at a different file from what you're executing and/or haven't saved the file or you have whitespace issues. Try copying the code from your post here to a new file and run that.

Comment: Yeah I am sure this is it. I have saved the file as dollars.py and i compiled it using python dollars.py and it asks for the input but when I enter 7 I get that error message.

Comment: Your new output is due to using `%` instead of `//`. Please see my answer.

Comment: `%` is the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). You want "floor division", which is the `//` operator instead. This is the reason you're seeing strange output.

Comment: why doesn't it do simple modulo division like C. Its least fussy

Comment: Your code wouldn't have worked in C neither, using the wrong operator. You do modulo and take the remainder as the number of bills you need. E.g. amount is 22. Then `22 % 20` is `2` in both pytohn and C. And this is not the answer you want.

Comment: NO it does run correctly in C. check it out

Comment: oops sorry, I have mis-typed it here. It is the normal division operator

Comment: Next time you put code on SO, just copy paste it, highlight it, and then click on the '{}' button so that it automatically indents and formats your code for you. You do not need to retype anything and you should not have confusing mistakes in your code that confuse people who are trying to answer your questions.

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra Please see the edit to my answer about `%` and `//`.

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra Your code works fine once I fix the extra indent (although I didn't get the same error0. Why is that there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying and pasting your code, it runs without errors, but it doesn't do what you want. I think you mix up `%` (modulo) with `//` (integer division) in order to determine the number of bills you need.

Also, when you see a lot of repetitive lines in your code, it might be the case that you should reorganize it a bit. Basically your `amt` boils down to this:

```
def amt():
    amount = int(input('Enter your amount: ') )
    for name, nomination in [ ('twenty', 20), ('ten', 10), ('five', 5), ('one', 1) ]:
        bills = amount // nomination
        amount -= bills * nomination
        if not bills: continue
        print('You need to pay {} {} dollar bill{}.'.format (bills, name, '' if bills == 1 else 's') )
```

Some words on integer division:

For all `a ∈ ℤ` and `b ∈ ℤ \ {0}`, there exist exactly one `d ∈ ℤ` and exactly one `r ∈ ℤ`, such that `a = db + r` and `0 ≤ r < b`. By definition `a // b = d` and `a % b = r`.

Comment: Note that copying and pasting the code loses the indentation error which was actually generating the error message that the OP reported.  You've fixed the code logic instead.

Answer (score 6):

It's not visually noticeable, but you're mixing tabs and spaces. It looks like that print statement is inside the `if`, but it's actually not.

This is what your source code looks like in Stack Overflow's text editor:

> [image]

Comment: Yep.  The OP can run `python -tt his_program_name.py` to confirm.

Comment: Why do you insist that it's perfectly indented when we all can see that it is not?